# SAS-Generating Table(s) based on conditional?

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, sas-macro, proc-sql

I am trying to write a macro that will create a new table dependent on certain criteria. The user can enter a single number or a range of numbers to filter the original data on.

For example, if the starting data set is shown below, the end user can choose to filter Col Z by a single number (ie: where Z=1) or a range of numbers (ie: where Z is between 1 and 5).

```
X    Y    Z
0    1    3
2    7    9
0     0   0
2     1   1
```

If the user wants to enter a range of numbers to filter on, there will be values populated for &start_range and &end_range. If the user wants to filter on a single number, &end_range will equal null.

I want code that will check if &end_range equals null. If it does, the where statement should create a new table for all rows where column Z=&start_range. If &end_range is NOT equal to null (it has a value populated), the where statement will create a new table for all rows where column Z is between &start_range and &end_range.

For a single value, (where &start_range=1 and &end_range=’ ‘), the resulting table would be:

```
X    Y    Z
2     1   1
```

For a range of values, (where &start_range=1 and &end_range=5), the resulting table would be:

```
X    Y    Z
0    1    3
2     1   1
```

This is the code I have so far, not 100% sure if syntax is correct so open to any and all suggestions, thanks!!:

```
 %macro filter();

proc sql;   
            create table filtered_data AS
            select raw_data.* 
            from raw_data
            WHERE       

                  %if &end_range NE '' %then %do;
                        Z between '&start_range' AND '&end_range';
                  %end;

                  %else %do;
                        Z = '&start_range';
                  %end;

            quit;

%mend;

%filter();
```

Comment: Questions that ask about a specific problem tend to work better for the Q&A format on this site than general requests for troubleshooting. Nevertheless, I have two suggestions. (1) The parameters of the macro should probably be listed in the `%macro` statement and specified when you invoke the macro. (2) You don't need to repeat the entire query; you could put the `%if %then %else` conditions inside the `where` statement to control only the lines of code that can change. This doesn't affect much, but it makes it clear to someone reading the code exactly which part of the code is conditional.

Comment: If the macro calls (and parameters) are going to be written by hand, then you may just want to pass in the where clause you want to use to the macro.  This exercise is only really worthwhile if you are going to be generating dynamic calls to the macro and don't know what the values of your parameters are going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a macro definition, I would suggest solving your problem by creating 2 simple macro variable for your start and end range. The start range would always have a valid number, but for end range you can code in logic to take start range value in case the end range value is blank/null. Check out the below code and let me know if it helps.

```
data raw_data;
infile datalines missover;
input X    Y    Z;
datalines4;
0    1    3
2    7    9
0     0   0
2     1   1
;;;;
run;
/*User enters the range*/
%let start_range=1;
%let end_range=5;

/*User entered data refining*/
%let end_range=%sysfunc(coalescec(&end_range,&start_range));

proc sql;
create table filtered_data AS
select *
from raw_data
where z between &start_range and &end_range
;
quit;
proc print data=filtered_data;run;
```

If you still prefer creating macro definition to solve your problem then try tweaking your first %IF statement in your macro definition and remove the single quotes you've applied to your macro variables in the WHERE statement in PROC SQL. Check out the updated macro definition.

```
%macro filter;
proc sql;   
            create table filtered_data AS
            select raw_data.* 
            from raw_data
            WHERE       
                  %if %length(&end_range) %then %do;
                        Z between &start_range AND &end_range;
                  %end;

                  %else %do;
                        Z = &start_range;
                  %end;
            quit;
%mend;
%filter;
```